# JPQL request with NEW That takes too much time

Tags: sql, jpa, jpql

I work with java and hibernate.  I try to implement that request in JPQL, but it takes really too much time (I even had to stop the proramm after a delay of 5 minutes) to run comparing to a close similar equivalent request made in pure SQL in the same condition

```
select NEW package.CustomObject(co.num, item, dim, mat, pro) from Object1 co LEFT JOIN co.items item LEFT JOIN item.dim dim LEFT JOIN item.mat mat LEFT JOIN item.pro pro
           where co.ins between '2018-12-26 01:00:00' and '2019-06-26 01:00:00' 
               or co.mod between '2018-12-26 01:00:00' and '2019-06-26 01:00:00'.
```

The CustomObject is the following

```
public class CustomObject {

    private String num;

    private OtherCustomObject other;

    public CustomObject(String num, ItemObject item, DimObject dim, MatObject mat, ProObject pro) {
        this.num = num;
        this.other = new OtherCustomObject(item, dim, mat, pro);
    }
```

}

```
public class OtherCustomObject {

    private String property1;
    private String property2;
    private String property3;
    private DimObject  dim;
    private MatObject  mat;
    private ProObject  pro;

    public OtherCustomObject(ItemObject item, DimObject dim, MatObject mat, ProObject pro) {
        this.property1 = item.getProperty1();
        this.property2 = item.getProperty2();
        this.property3 = item.getProperty3();
        this.dim = dim;
        this.mat = mat;
        this.pro = pro; 
    }
}
```

Here is the close similar equivalent request made in pure SQL

```
select  co.num
from    table1    co  left join ItemTable item on item.ou = co.ou left join DimTable dim on dim.item_id = item.id left join MatTable mat on mat.item_id = item.id left join ProTable pro on pro.item_id = item.id 
where   co.ins   between '2018-12-26 01:00:00' and '2019-06-26 01:00:00'
    or  co.mod   between '2018-12-26 01:00:00' and '2019-06-26 01:00:00';
```

This request is almost instantaneous. So what's wrong with my JPQL request ?

Comment: What is the database? Can you share your entities code? Did you use the `setParameter` or create the JPQL with hard-coded parameters? There are another SQL being generated when you execute the JPQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason is there were too much data to collect. When I run the following request

```
select co.num from Object1 co LEFT JOIN co.items item LEFT JOIN item.dim dim LEFT JOIN item.mat mat LEFT JOIN item.pro pro
           where co.ins between '2018-12-26 01:00:00' and '2019-06-26 01:00:00' 
               or co.mod between '2018-12-26 01:00:00' and '2019-06-26 01:00:00'.
```

I have 105 000 results. So the server lacks memory to render the other objects and create CustomObject